# Why does my program return a "NoneType" object is not subscriptable error when I clearly defined it?

Tags: python, list, substring, nonetype

My program should return the set of largest common substrings in two strings, it worked fine until it got to line 6: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Here's the code:

```
def longest_substring(a,b):
    longest = [""]
    for i in range(1,len(a) + 1):
        for j in range(0,len(a) - i):
            if a[j:j+i] in b:
                if len(longest[0]) != len(a[j:j+i]):
                    longest = [a[j:j+i]]
                else:
                    longest = longest.append(a[j:j+i])
    return tuple(longest)
print(longest_substring("abcdeghij","bcdefghij"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `append` works inplace

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now when I run the code, it only returns ("bcde",), does anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: That's a triple containing 1 item. Take the 0the index of the result

Comment: I don't know what your code is supposed to do, so potentially you have an error in the logic. But that isn't what the original question was about

Answer (score 2):

```
longest = longest.append(a[j:j+i])
```

This line sets `longest` to `None` because that's what `append` returns.

`append` is a in-place update of the list. All you need is:

```
longest.append(a[j:j+i])
```

Comment: Why not close as a dupe :(

Comment: Did not find one. Voted to close as dup.